# Error message when trying to create Gemfile

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

Can someone please break down the very very beginnings of how to run a Gemfile. I've read the Bundler webiste and it says I have to type "Gem Install Bundler" then source "https://rubygems.org". Everytime I do that I get an error message saying "Source is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I've tried creating an empty gemfile first by typing "bundle init" but when I type my source, I get the error message. I also found some literature about telling it to look in github and tried to direct it to the actual project in github but it gave me the same error message.

I am completely new to coding but have to run some gems off a file in github to test my answers on some questions I've been given. There's a gemfile on the github page with this in it:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem rspec

gem pry

Any help for an absolute beginner is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this is not a tutorial site. A Google search for that error message will turn up many results (most of which are here) for what that error means and how to fix it.

Comment: ' type "Install Bundler" ' - no, you are supposed to install bundler, by typing `gem install bundler`. All lowercase.

Comment: @KenWhite I did try google first of course, I couldn't find anything that matched my problem exactly enough to be of any relevant use. There was an error on my part in the initial post, I entered `gem install bundler` (not "Install Bundler" like I had said) and that intalls bundler but I've followed the online tutorials for two days now and it doesn't work. So I'm literally out of ideas now.

Comment: The search should be on *is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*. The fact it refers to *source* is irrelevant; the answer to the question is the same. Something is not on the PATH and therefore the executable can't be found, and the OS doesn't know what to do. Quit being so literal, and try to apply other answers to your situation. Trying to find a post that **exactly** matches your situation is ludicrous. *I'm trying to add two ints named a and b* Ok. there's  a post here that answers that for you. *No, it adds two ints named x and y.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `source 'http://rubygems.org'` not `https://` which isn't supported yet

Comment: Just tried that. Still not working. Thanks anyway. The problem is I just don't know enough about my terminal to make sense of the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
gem install bundler
```

then you can author a `Gemfile` like

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'pry'
```

after this, you may run

```
bundle install
```

and as an outcome rspec and pry gems will be installed in your system.

You have more information about [Gemfiles in Bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.6/gemfile.html) official documentation.

Also, bear in mind that you are installing those gems system-wide, this might cause dependency problems and/or version problems if you have more projects where those gems are required. If that is the case, I recommend you using something to control Ruby versions and gemsets, for example [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

Comment: Sorry I did actually mean "Gem install bundler". I get a message back saying it's installed and my terminal then goes back to how it was before and when I type source, I get the error message. Any ideas?

Comment: I've correct it now to prevent others from pointing it out. Thanks.

Comment: @KDS could you share the contents of your Gemfile?

Comment: The only thing in the Gemfile is what I posted before,                           
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'pry'